# Why does the LEAP 1A HPT run at such a high RPM?

Tags: jet-engine, turbofan, turbine

I've watched the N2 on the LEAP sit at 100% at cruise and fluctuate as high as 101%.  Why does the HPT run at such a high RPM?

Comment: If it helps, the [EASA Type Cert](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/EASA%20E%20110%20TCDS%20Issue%202%20LEAP-1A_1C_20161103_1.0.pdf) shows that the max N2 RPM is `High pressure rotor (N2): 19391 (116.5 % - 100 % N2 is defined as 16645 rpm)`

Comment: What were you expecting it to be?  What other engine is your basis for comparison?  I'd say 100% N2 is fairly reasonable for cruise for modern GE cores.